# Transform a Column conditional on another Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Age     Age Type
12       Years
5        Days
13       Hours
20       Months
...      ......
```

I want to have my Age column in Years...so depending on Age Type, if it is either in Days, Hours, or Months, I will have to perform a scalar operation. I tried to implement a for loop but not sure if I'm going about it the right way. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your current attempt to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a map `dict`

```
d={'Years':1,'Days':1/365,'Hours':1/364/24,'Months':1/12}
df.Age*df.AgeType.map(d)
Out[373]: 
0    12.000000
1     0.013699
2     0.001488
3     1.666667
dtype: float64
```